# Unit root test (for stationarity) in R using IPS test (purtest in plm package) for unbalanced panel data

Tags: r, statistics, plm

I am trying to run unit root test for stationarity in R, for unbalanced panel data. I want to run IPS test using purtest from plm package.

```
purtest(D1$int_rate, data = D1, test="ips", lags = "SIC", pmax = 2 , exo="trend")
```

Although it does not work and keeps throwing this error.

```
 Error in object[1:(length(object) - 1)] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I can not find any solution on the internet or in the package documentation. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: if you're using data = D1 then you probably want to use the formula interface: `purtest(int_rate ~ 1, data = D1, ...)`. See the examples in the help.

Comment: Hi, I used 

purtest(int_rate ~ 1, data = D1, test="ips", exo="trend", lags = "SIC", pmax = 2 )

But it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plm::purtest: Error in object\[1:(length(object) - x)\] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71948577/plmpurtest-error-in-object1lengthobject-x-only-0s-may-be-mixed-wi)